# I want to cut variable on another variables using Python

Tags: python, string

I have a variable `c`.

```
c = ' FR,DE,UK,IT '
```

I want to cut this variable on another variables: `c1`, `c2`, `c3`, `c4`

So that `c1 = 'FR'`,  `c2 = 'DE'`, `c3 = 'UK'`, `c4 = 'IT'`.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
c1, c2, c3, c4 = c.split(',')
```

Note that if, as I suspect, you're hoping for an arbitrary number of dynamic variables to be created depending on the length of the list, you should *not* try to do that. Keep them in a list:

```
c_list = c.split(',')
```

Comment: And of course the usual if separately named variables are required, then just a `dict` instead of `globals()`.... `d = {'c{}'.format(idx):val for idx, val in enumerate(c_list, 1)}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) function of strings:

```
c1, c2, c3, c4 = c.split(',')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> clist = c.strip().split(',')  # 'strip' removes the surrounding spaces
>>> clist
['FR', 'DE', 'UK', 'IT']
```

Now your "`cn`" can be accessed via `clist[n-1]`:

```
>>> clist[0]  # c1
'FR'
>>> clist[1]  # c2
'DE'
>>> clist[2]  # c3
'UK'
>>> clist[3]  # c4
'IT'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c1, c2, c3, c4 = c.split(',')
```

should do the trick. This takes advantage of the destructuring assignment feature of Python where a sequence/iterable is matched with the variables on the left.

Answer (score 0):

You could divide it to lists by -

```
clist = c.split(",")
```